# How to do "pthread" under windows?

Tags: c++, c, windows, multithreading, cross-platform

I have tried:

1) [POSIX Threads for Win32](http://sources.redhat.com/pthreads-win32/), [myfiles1](http://repository.atwebpages.com/mavStar/pthreadUnderWin.zip)

What I did was copying the files in “lib” and “include” folders form the "Pre-built.2" directory to my project directory, and add this line to mapping.cpp

```
#pragma comment(lib, "pthreadVC2.lib")
```

2) and [this tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cross-platform/crossplatformmutex.aspx), [myfiles2](http://repository.atwebpages.com/mavStar/winThread.zip)

But I couldn't figure out how to change this part:

```
#if defined(LINUX)
    pthread_t thread_print;

    int iret_print;
    iret_print = pthread_create( &thread_print, NULL, glRender, (void*) &globalOG);
#elif defined(WINDOWS)
    HANDLE  thread_id;
    CreateThread( 
        NULL,                   // default security attributes
        0,                      // use default stack size  
        glRender,               // thread function name
        NULL,                   // argument to thread function 
        0,                      // use default creation flags 
        &thread_id);            // returns the thread identifier               
#endif
```

I probably have done something wrong with the Win implementation

```
#elif defined(WINDOWS)
DWORD WINAPI glRender( void *ptr )
```

Comment: @Miranda: Care to explain what exactly happened rather than just the `Neither worked`?

Comment: If you can't make those tutorials work, perhaps you'd like to use C++0x and `<thread>` + `<mutex>`? Built-in cross-platform portability...

Comment: "I haven't had any luck, neither worked". Come on, we can't do anything with that information. Details please! If you can't even spend the time to detail what you did and why it failed, why would you expect us to care about your problem?

Comment: @Kerrek SB: That is a wrong advice, wrong reasoning to switch to C++0x threads. The very reason of existance of Posix was portability.

Comment: @Miranda: start with this: https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/ , include pthread.h and don't forget to tell the linker to about pthread lib.

Comment: @Als: Could you explain a bit what's wrong with using the standard library? Wouldn't it give you access the best implementation on every supported platform? On Posix you'll get Posix threads anyway, and on Windows you'll get the native threads, almost exactly what those tutorials spell out by hand with #defines, non?

Comment: @Kerrek SB: Your reasoning of `Portability` is a `wrong reasoning to switch to C++0x threads` your comment never reasoned `Efficiency` to make the switch.

Comment: @Als: POSIX was never designed to be portable. It was designed to be portable **between UNIX variants only** (It's the **P** ortable **O** perating **S** ystem specification for UN **IX**). Lots of systems are not Unix variants. PThreads are not portable to anything that's not Unix (e.g. Windows NT running on the Win32 Subsystem). (PThreads will actually probably be better than the C++0x threads in terms of efficiency given that C++0x threads are implemented in terms of POSIX threads)

Comment: @Billy ONeal: Isn't POSIX also available on windows systems? How is POSIX available on Windows different from POSIX on Unix? Maybe the internal implementation don't remain the same but I guess the interfaces remain the same on windows or Unix or Linux, does that not make users projects portable across platforms? All one has to do is link to appropriate OS POSIX library without changing any implementation in their projects.

Comment: @Als: There is a POSIX subsystem available for Windows NT (called "interix") but it is not typically installed on consumer versions of windows, and does not give PThreads support to applications running on the Win32 Subsystem. It's available on the ultimate client versions of Windows, and also for Windows Server Enterprise and higher.

Comment: Please could anyone tell me where to get this `pthreadVC2.lib` library?